# menus don't consistently drop on the first click

Tags: windows-7

I used to think that I just didn't click squarely on the menu. Now, that I am paying closer attention, I see that sometimes it takes several clean clicks that are targeted squarely on the menu before the menu drops.

This is starting to annoy me. My PC is loaded with RAM and the proc utilization is low.

What the heck?

Comment: What menus, in what programs?

Comment: Visual Studio, Windows Explorer. Any menus. Probably any menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this as a test: Right click on Computer>Properties>Advanced System Properties>Advanced>Performance>Visual Effects, and set them as I have them in the screenshot, and see if that makes any difference. If it does, you will then know where to look, and you can play with the setting from there to balance performance with appearance.

I would also be looking at my mouse driver, and mouse settings in Control Panel.

[image]

Comment: Son of a gun. I think you fixed me! I'll keep clicking away but this looks VERY promising. I'm surprise you suggested a custom setting rather than the "performance" one. Any reason? Thank you VERY much!

Comment: Hmm. I haven't looked at my mouse driver settings, but now that you mention it, I did upgrade the driver-Why I did I have no clue. It was working before. What kind of extra functionality was I expecting out of my mouse?

Comment: I just turn off all the crap I don't like, and that is the set of settings I have come up with over the years. I hate things like the windows fading open...When I click on it, I just want it open...NOW. :) I mostly just turn off all "Animates", "Fades", and "Slides".

Comment: Ya man.  I turn off pretty much everything but preview, clearType and aero.  Everything else is a waste of time. . .

Comment: I thought the suggestion fixed the problem. It's still behaving pretty badly, though I think it help. How do I roll back my mouse driver update? The update was before my oldest restore point and the mouse driver "Rollback" button is disabled...

Comment: If the rollback is disabled, you can only re-download an older version and install it again. What is the model of the mouse, and the current driver version?

Comment: Logitech M-BD58. I hooked up a different mouse and I am working great. I'm content.

Comment: Thanks for marking it again. Even though it was just the mouse, I am sure that you will still appreciate the changes you made to the settings in the screenshot. They really improve performance, IMO.